# Dynamically Adding select fields and validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding select fields using javascript & its working fine I want to add valiadation

```
<select>
  <option>8mm</option>
  <option>10mm</option>
  <option>12mm</option>
</select>
<select>
  <option>8mm</option>
  <option>10mm</option>
  <option>12mm</option>
</select>
<select>
  <option>8mm</option>
  <option>10mm</option>
  <option>12mm</option>
</select>
```

If user select 8mm in the first select then 8mm will disable in other two select tag.

**Here is the JS Code for adding select field**

```
var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1
var maxField = 6; //Input fields increment limitation
var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper
var fieldHTML = `<div>
<span class="w-1/2 mr-2">
    <label for="basicRate">Basic</label>
    <select name="basicRate[]" id="basicRate" onchange="getBasicVal(this);" required>
        <option value="8">8mm</option>
        <option value="10">10mm</option>
        <option value="12">12mm</option>
        <option value="16">16mm</option>
        <option value="20">20mm</option>
        <option value="25">25mm</option>
    </select>
</span>
<span class="w-1/2">
    <label for="">Quantity (in tons)</label>
    <input id="quantity" type="text" name="quantity" placeholder="" required />
</span><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button" title="Remove">Remove</a>
</div>`; 



//New input field html

//Once add button is clicked
$(addButton).click(function(){
    //Check maximum number of input fields
    if(x < maxField){ 
        x++; //Increment field counter
        $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); //Add field html
        
    }
});

//Once remove button is clicked
$(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove(); //Remove field html
    x--; //Decrement field counter
});
```

**Here is the UI**

[image]

As you see first two drop-down has same value 10mm means user can select same values.
Am looking for simple validation if user select some option then he or she wont select the same value in other dropdown.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through `selected` options using `each` loop and using this selected value compare it with other options if matches `disabled` that option from other select-box.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).on("change", ".basicRate", function() {
  $("select option").attr("disabled", false);//remove disable from all
  //loop through all select box(selected option)
  $(".basicRate option:selected").each(function() {
    var value = $(this).val()
    //loop through all option(not selected option) if you don't want to disable selected option .. else just use `.basicRate option`
    $(".basicRate option:not(:selected)").each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == value) {
        $(this).attr("disabled", true);
      }
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span class="w-1/2 mr-2">
    <label for="basicRate">Basic</label>
    <!--use class-->
    <select name="basicRate[]" class="basicRate"  required>
        <option value="8">8mm</option>
        <option value="10">10mm</option>
        <option value="12">12mm</option>
        <option value="16">16mm</option>
        <option value="20">20mm</option>
        <option value="25">25mm</option>
    </select>
</span>
  <span class="w-1/2">
    <label for="">Quantity (in tons)</label>
    <input id="quantity" type="text" name="quantity" placeholder="" required />
</span><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button" title="Remove">Remove</a>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="w-1/2 mr-2">
    <label for="basicRate">Basic</label>
    <select name="basicRate[]" class="basicRate"  required>
        <option value="8">8mm</option>
        <option value="10">10mm</option>
        <option value="12">12mm</option>
        <option value="16">16mm</option>
        <option value="20">20mm</option>
        <option value="25">25mm</option>
    </select>
</span>
  <span class="w-1/2">
    <label for="">Quantity (in tons)</label>
    <input id="quantity" type="text" name="quantity" placeholder="" required />
</span><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button" title="Remove">Remove</a>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="w-1/2 mr-2">
    <label for="basicRate">Basic</label>
    <select name="basicRate[]" class="basicRate"  required>
        <option value="8">8mm</option>
        <option value="10">10mm</option>
        <option value="12">12mm</option>
        <option value="16">16mm</option>
        <option value="20">20mm</option>
        <option value="25">25mm</option>
    </select>
</span>
  <span class="w-1/2">
    <label for="">Quantity (in tons)</label>
    <input id="quantity" type="text" name="quantity" placeholder="" required />
</span><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button" title="Remove">Remove</a>
</div>
```